# Unnessary character on post after restore

Tags: errors, debug, wp-debug

Recently i restored the wordpress post . Now I am getting so much problem with it.

In post there are unknown characters like Â

like you can see in

[image]

There are othermany such character.

I actually want to know reason why is this happening?

Database is sat to UTF 8 and wp-config is also at UTF-8 then why is this happening .

Thanks

Comment: You state that you 'restored the wordpress post'.  How?  What exactly was done to introduce this problem?

Comment: Yes backupped using phpmyadmin . downloaded sql file in past

Comment: And restored using it using import.